# Impossible to ping with iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc

Tags: linux, ping, ad-hoc-network

PCs:

1. Linux Mint 17.2 with Broadcom BCM43225
2. Ubuntu 14.04 with PRO/Intel Wireless and iwl3945 driver

I've run the following commands on the two PCs:

```
service network-manager stop
ip link set wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 1 essid XYZ
ip link set wlan0 up
ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev wlan0
```

Naturally on the second I gave `192.168.1.2`: until now no errors were reported.

When I try to ping each other, though, I get `destination unreachable` and I don't understand why because when I do `iwconfig wlan0` I see that the interfaces are both in ad-hoc, both on essid ABC both on channel 1, but with different cells even if the pc are 2cm distant.
I don't know if the cell is the problem, but I don't think, because I can't even find a way to fix it.
However I think that problem is on the second PC (the one with Ubuntu) because when I connect my phone to the first one PC running the same commands they can ping each other.

**Linux Mint 17.2**
[image]

**Ubuntu 14.04**
[image]

Comment: You're setting both PCs to the same IP address?

Comment: Nono, one has `192.168.1.1` the other has `192.168.1.2`

Comment: Can you take a screenshot or copy paste the `ifconfig` (or similar) results on the machines?

Comment: @Leathe done, added.

Comment: Alright, don't really see anything off there. You don't happen to be using `Realtek 8192cu Linux` drivers? Apparently that has been causing other people very similar issues.

Comment: On the one with Ubuntu I am using iwl3945 driver, on the one with Linux Mint I'm using `driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574)` (from `lshw -C network`)

Comment: The Cell is actually the address of the access point that you are connecting to (in Ad-Hoc mode) so from what you post the two computers are connecting to two different access points (or two interfaces on the same access point). You sure there is a route between the two?

Comment: @ojs the cell is the address of the access point if we are talking about infrastracture mode (managed mode), but we are talking about ad hoc mode

Comment: @welcome that contradicts with what [this](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/iwconfig.htm) page says.

Comment: @ojs mmmmhh, but should the ESSID identify cells which are part of the same virtual network? According to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_network_interface_controller all the nodes in an ad hoc network must have the same channel and SSID.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae as you can see from the screenshots I didn't misspelled the network I wish I did :( However on which systems did you try it?

Comment: According to [this ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/263541) then the iwl3945 driver has had problems with adhoc, see if your `dmesg` shows any errors.

Comment: @ojs It's a bug of 2009, which has been fixed and the patch brough to the mainline kernel (still a 2. series back then).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae why did you remove your answer?